# "Aforementioned" or "beforementioned"

Tags: etymology, prefixes

I asked a question on the origin of the word *aforementioned*. To me, it would seem that this word should be *beforementioned* instead. Why does it begin with *afore-*?

Also, does this mean *afore* can be used as a substitute for *before*?

Comment: Did you check any of there words in a dictionary? You'll find afore and before there, and can check the etymology of aforementioned.

Comment: *Afore* also forms part of the word *aforesaid*, and possibly other composites. So far as I know, there are no compound words that use *before*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: beforehand

Comment: Are you asking why a particular word formation is more popular than the one you feel is more logical? Or are you asking for the definition of "afore"? The first is probably unanswerable and the second is general reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED’s earliest citation is dated 1587, in a work by Sir Philip Sydney. *Afore* is from Old English *on foran*, with the second element meaning *in front, in advance*. In the OED’s words, ‘*Afore* is now mostly obsolete in literature, its place being taken by *before*, but it is retained in the Bible and Prayer-book, is common in the dialects generally, as well as in "vulgar" London speech, and in nautical language.’ The earliest occurrence of *before* predates that of *afore*, despite its Old English origin, by several centuries.